# How to set adaptive background to the image?

Tags: html, css, position

> Before(On my screen resolution (1024px))

[image]

> After (On the other resulution - for example screen width:1500px)

[image]

```css
#quotes_div img{
    width: 100vh;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}
#quotes_div{
    position: relative;
}
#quotes_div #img{
    width: 82.5%;
    height: 38.5vh;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="quotes_div">
    <h3>My favorite quotes to which I adhere</h3>
    <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-quote-right fa-2x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <p>Even an impossible dream can lead to action</p>
    <div id="img">
     <img src="assets/fielding.jpg" alt="Field">
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to the picture Nr.1 and "border"(background) will have same resolution. + I am sorry (I am not at formating text on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your image responsive, and stay within the red border, don't force a specific height, just specify container and image as 100% and add padding around the image to show the red background.

See this example it now works, add or remove padding as you see fit:

```css
#quotes_div img{
 width: 100%;
}
#quotes_div{
position: relative;
}
#quotes_div #img{
 width: 100%;
 background: red;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="quotes_div">
     <h3>My favorite quotes to which I adhere</h3>
     <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-2x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <i class="fa fa-quote-right fa-2x fa-inverse" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     <p>Even an impossible dream can lead to action</p>
     <div id="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x350" alt="Field">
     </div>
    </div>
```